# Android Error - Unfortunately [Projectname] has stopped (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm running my application. I don't insert numberic into edittext then I click convert button I received error as Unfortunately TemporaryConvert has stopped.

This is My java File

```
package com.example.temporaryconvert;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RadioGroup radiogroup;
EditText input;
TextView solution;
Button con;
String num;
int i_input;
double sumfah,sumcel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    radiogroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

    input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    solution = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    con = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    con.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            i_input = Integer.parseInt(num = input.getText().toString());
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####.00");

            RadioButton rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0),
                    rb2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);

            if(rb1.isChecked()){
                sumfah=(i_input*1.8)+32;
                solution.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(sumfah)));
            }
            else if(rb2.isChecked()){
                sumcel=(i_input-32)*1.8;
                solution.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(sumcel)));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

My xml File

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/LightGray"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/tem_text"
    android:textColor="@color/LightRed"
    android:textSize="34sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/con_discrip_text"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit"
        android:textColor="@color/LightRed"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius"
        android:textColor="@color/LightRed"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Enter Temporary"
    android:textColor="@color/LightRed"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:ems="7"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/LightRed" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="00.00"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/LightRed"
    android:text="Convert"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/White" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please Help Me !!! TT

Comment: Please post your LogCat error.

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: I second @2Dee [with this](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/94/94eb289f247f6e711a9975bed6783d1db4a15af4a9f2b7cd8f1a560a3bfb540a.jpg).

Comment: Most probably a `NumberFormatException`: check if `input.getText().toString()` is not empty before parsing it as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Init radiobutton rb1 & rb2 in oncreate() or method which does not have parameter as View coz findviewbyId will find that component in that view by Id.

like:

```
 rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
 rb2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
```

Change your onclick method: Try to fetch data separately (e.g num)

```
num= input.getText().toString().trim();
if(num.length()!=0){ // check if its empty or not
i_input = Integer.parseInt(num);
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####.00");

            if(rb1.isChecked()){
                sumfah=(i_input*1.8)+32;
                solution.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(sumfah)));
            }
            else if(rb2.isChecked()){
                sumcel=(i_input-32)*1.8;
                solution.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(sumcel)));
            }
}
```